# Asp.net DirectoryBrowser Feature, how to control sort?

Tags: asp.net-core

I've got an asp.net core webapp which uses the directory browser feature setup in my `Startup.cs` like this.

```
app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
     Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "youtubeDLs")),
        RequestPath = "/Downloads"
    });
```

I surface this as a partial like this.

```
<div id="dynamicContentContainer"></div>
<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#dynamicContentContainer").load("/Downloads")
    }, 2800);

</script>
```

And this is great, I have my file browser which I want, it's lovely.

[image]

BUT, I don't have any control on file sorting, and I'd love to sort the files on `DateModified` or `DateCreated`.

I've scoured the [API Catalog on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.directorybrowseroptions.formatter?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_DirectoryBrowserOptions_Formatter) but can't find anything.  Is this just something I can't control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply override `HtmlDirectoryFormatter`

```cs
public class SortedHtmlDirectoryFormatter : HtmlDirectoryFormatter
{
    public SortedHtmlDirectoryFormatter(HtmlEncoder encoder) : base(encoder) { }

    public override Task GenerateContentAsync(HttpContext context, IEnumerable<IFileInfo> contents)
    {
        var sorted = contents.OrderBy(f => f.LastModified);
        return base.GenerateContentAsync(context, sorted);
    }
}
```

and use it in your app:

```cs
app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions
{
    FileProvider = staticPathProvider,
    RequestPath = "/Downloads",
    Formatter = new SortedHtmlDirectoryFormatter(HtmlEncoder.Default)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no options to config sort in this middleware, I've raised this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20174) in github. Asp.net core has no plan to add this feature either. since UseDirectoryBrowser is more like a diagnostic tool. To achieve this you'd better replace DirectoryBrowserOptions.Formatter to customize the view. You can copy [HtmlDirectoryFormatter](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/19d2f6124f5d04859e350d1f5a01e994e14ef1ce/src/Middleware/StaticFiles/src/HtmlDirectoryFormatter.cs#L20) and customize it to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

I made this simple nuget package [SortedHtmlDirectoryFormatter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SortedHtmlDirectoryFormatter/) according to Elendil's suggestion.

```cs
app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(rootDirectory),
    RequestPath = "/your-request-path",
    Formatter = new SortedHtmlDirectoryFormatter()
});
```

This will sort the file list by `LastModified` in descending order.